# How to stop an UIView animation

Tags: objective-c, ipad, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I have several `UIImageViews` within a `UIScrollView` that I want to wiggle when the user long-presses one of them. So similar to the behavior you get when you long-press an icon in your iPad/iPhone menu.

So I have the following:

```
- (void)startWiggling {

    for (UIImageView *touchView in [scrollView subviews]) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"wiggle" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:FLT_MAX];

        //wiggle 1 degree both sides
        touchView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation();
        touchView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.0174532925);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }    

}

- (void)stopWiggling {
    NSLog(@"Stop wiggling");    
}
```

This works fine. The issue is... How can I make it **stop** wiggling after the user has pressed a button? I have a button and connected it etc and it's reaching the `stopWiggling` method, so that's fine. But so...

1. How do I remove the UIView animation from these `UIImageViews`?
2. Can I bind this action to the user pressing the **home button** on their device?

Comment: Not sure how to answer the first bit but pressing the Home Button will cause the termination of the App to the Home Screen. There is no way to bind that key because it is held by the System

Comment: @Suhail Patel I know, but I thought there might be a way to override the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method and check whether or not the images are wiggling. And if so, stop the wiggle and cancel the application from entering background mode. But I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: You can't stop it from going into the background but you can stop the wiggling in that method. It doesn't give you an option...

Comment: I believe that the best way in 2018 would be to use UIViewPropertyAnimator

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

then

```
 [myView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

or

```
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Comment: Ye you're right. I knew about the `removeAllAnimations` method but I didn't even bother trying as I didn't place the animation on the view's layer but on the view itself. But surprisingly this did work.. =/

Comment: the problem with this is that if you wish to resume the animations on the same layer, it wont work again as the layer has all the animations removed from it.

Comment: To resume and pause animation , you can see this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1673/_index.html.