# iOS - How to stop UIView animations at a particular frame

Tags: ios, animation, frame

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cancel a UIView animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554997/cancel-a-uiview-animation)

i need to stop an UIView animation. I know i can use `[object.layer removeAllAnimations];` but this doesn't stop the animation, but "skip" it. So, if my original animation is :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:8.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^ (void) {
        [ingredient setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 34, 45)];
    } completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"Completed");
    }];
```

the object ingredient will have the frame that would have if the animation had finished. Instead, i want the object STOP in specific point, without the animation complete.

Comment: If you turn off the device, all animations will stop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel a UIView animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554997/cancel-a-uiview-animation) and [How to stop an UIView animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204602/how-to-stop-an-uiview-animation)

Comment: Not a duplicate, this question is regarding 'pausing' an animation, not cancelling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pause, but don't intend to start again, try:

```
CALayer *objectPresentationLayer = [object.layer presentationLayer];
object.layer.transform = objectPresentationLayer.transform;
[object.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

If you want to pause and resume animations, check this out from the Apple Q&A:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1673.html

Comment: This seems to move the animation into it's finished state on ios 9?

Comment: Didn't work for me either, but `progressView.layer.frame = progressView.layer.presentation()!.frame` did work