# Stop an animation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

#### Possible Repeat

- [Cancel a UIView animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554997/cancel-a-uiview-animation)
- [How to stop UIView animation at a particular frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140637/ios-how-to-stop-uiview-animations-at-a-particular-frame)
- [How to stop an UIView animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204602/how-to-stop-an-uiview-animation)

I currently have a block animation that goes like so...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:nil animations:^{
self.imageView.image = /* function that returns image */
} completion:^(BOOL finished){

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:nil animations:^{
self.imageView.image = /* function that returns image */
} completion:^(BOOL finished){

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:nil animations:^{
self.imageView.image = /* function that returns image */
} completion:^(BOOL finished){/*...*/}
```

I'm wondering how to cancel this on the `viewWillDisappear`. I have tried...

- `[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];`
- `[self.imageView.layer removeAllAnimations];`
- setting the `finished` variable to both `YES` and `NO`.
- inserting a `if(done==YES) return` into the `completion{}` block.
- ...and committing a short animation (after  after `removeAllAnimations`) as in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/scottsievert/5332606).

None of these methods work. My animation is still being computed when I want it to stop, and I have ensured that the function to stop it is being called.

My guess is that I'm sending the "stop" message to the wrong object, and that it's a simple fix that I don't have enough experience to handle.

Comment: should it be `if (finished) [UIView animateWithDuration ...` to be able to cancel animation sequence?

Comment: I think @voromax is correct, finished will be set to NO if the animation was cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try simply making **self.imageView = nil**?

Comment: Yes, that works for me! The animations finish super quick because it returns an error each time.

Comment: This might be more of a quick fix. If you have some time later, I might examine it a bit deeper, but happy it worked for you.

Comment: A quick fix is good enough for me. I'm close to having the app done.

Comment: But now, with iOS 7, the quick fix is not enough. It's telling me that that will produce a critical error in future versions. So, another method?

Comment: Nevermind. I had a method that I wanted to be done as quickly as possible, so I just inserted an if statement in the function. It was along the lines of `if (condition != met)`.